# Div not being centre aligned inside another div

Tags: html, css

I can't seem to centre align my div(title) which sits inside another div.

HTML

```
<div class="wrapper">
   <div id="header">
      <div class="title">Home</div>
   </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
#header {
  position:relative;
  width:1200px;
  height:400px;
  margin:auto;
  border:1px solid red;
}

.title {
  position:absolute;
  width:1000px;
  height:140px;
  background-color:red;
  margin:auto;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Remove `position: absolute` and it works perfectly.

Position: absolute is only necessary when you need very specific placement outside of the normal document flow. In this case, nothing special is needed apart from automatic left and right margins, which you already have.

Answer (score 0):

you are mixing stuff.
Remove position absolute.

or if you want it to be absolute you can do this

```
.title {
position:absolute;
width:1000px;
height:140px;
left: 50%;
background-color:red;
margin-left:-500px;
}
```